# Xserv Mac os x server serial number

Tags: macos

I Have a Xserve!When i Power on the xserv this window opens!where can i found serial number? or how i can install a new mac os x? please help me[image]

Answer (score 1):

The serial number is printed on a card that came with the installation DVDs.  If you don't have this card, or the DVDs, then maybe the original owner still has a record of it.

Comment: thank you! can i install a newest version?

Comment: That depends on how old the Xserve is.  According to http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201475 only the 2009 Xserve is supported.  And, even if you upgraded the base OS, you would need to purchase the Server.app for Yosemite in order to do server-type stuff.